# Worklight encryption for Windows 8 Store web resources

Tags: windows-store-apps, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I'm currently porting an application as a Windows Store App with Worklight 6.1. Is there a feature to encrypt web resources similar to what the iPad and Android environments have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypted Offline Cache is not available for the Windows 8 environment in Worklight 6.1.

It is alsos not available for this environment in recently released Worklight 6.2.
However, in Worklight 6.2 you can use the newly added JSONStore support in Windows 8 to protect your data.

---

The Encrypt Web Resources feature is available only for Android and iOS.
You can submit a feature request so that it will be considered for a future release of Worklight: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I want to protect the javascript source files. The data is not an issue. In iPad and android we can just set the application descriptor so that all web resources, including javascript files are encrypted and cannot be opened from the installer. However, I'm not sure there is a similiar feature for Windows Store App.

Comment: The feature you are asking is available for Android and iOS only.